# What is my Mac doing at 12 at night? Random process heats up Macbook to 80c while it's sleeping

Tags: bug

So I put the laptop to sleep around 5pm and then all of a sudden when I'm going to bed the laptop fans start going crazy. Weird, since the laptop is closed and it's been quiet for quite some time.

I open the laptop and login and my surprise theres a process going balls crazy and the temperature is going above 80c.

What is this `ffmpeg` doing? Has anyone else had such weird things happen to them like this? This isn't the first time it's happenend.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A quick search on google led me to this [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org) site. It looks like a proper utility for media file type conversion and real-time encoders from different sources.

This app takes up so many resources and heating your Mac could potentially be caused by some work in progress. If you are the one who started the job, such as converting a large media file or recording something from somewhere, you should know it best and decide for yourself whether you want to stop it.

If you did not, however, consider ending the task and check the integrity of the process. Take a look at the location of the executable and see if it looks out of place.

It could also be a bug in the software itself (or misuse of the app) which most likely can be fixed by a restart of your Mac or reinstalling of the app.

If you have never heard of the app before and think that you did not install it by accident or anything, proceed to remove it as soon as possible.

If it is an app in your Applications folder, consider using [App Cleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) to scan for hidden related files or folders and remove it or just do <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> on the app.

If it is in a form of shell script or any file without a file extension, directly delete it together with any other files or folders you see beside it that looks like it belongs to the executable.